pipewire handsfree not used for calls
on my debian dist (12 bookworm), after installing pipewire+wireplumber, including pipewire-pulse and pipewire-alsa and libspa-0.2-bluetooth, bluetootctl shows that my machine's profiles include "Audio Sink", "Audio Source", and "Handsfree" (among many others).
I understand that I can connect my phone to it, and it will act as handsfree set.
I connect my (Android) phone, and indeed I can play music from my phone on my PC sound card, as expected.
now, when I initialize a phone call (or whatsapp call or whatever) - the phone thinks it's handling the call through bluetooth, but actually there is no sound at all, not recording nor playing, not on the phone nor on the PC.
what am I missing?
